# How to display image like gmail displays?

Tags: image, asp.net-core

ASP.NET Core app.

If user is signed in I see:

> Hello @UserManager.GetUserName(User)!

At page:

```
@if (SignInManager.IsSignedIn(User))
{
    <form asp-area="" asp-controller="Account" asp-action="Logout" method="post" id="logoutForm" class="navbar-right">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li>
                <a asp-area="" asp-controller="Manage" asp-action="Index" title="Manage">Hello @UserManager.GetUserName(User)!</a>
            </li>
            <li>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-link navbar-btn navbar-link">Log out</button>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </form>
}
```

I want to display image like gmail displays in right-upper corner: abbreviation with 2 letters of username.  How to generate and display the image?

Comment: If you want to display two letters, why do you want an image? [For example](https://jsfiddle.net/vLqdchrt/).

Comment: Yes, DavidG, you are right, it is not image, but 1-2 letters only. Write you message I will mark it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to generate an image, you can do this completely with HTML and CSS. For example:

```css
.username-wrapper {
  display: table;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.username {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 20px;
  text-align: center;
  color: white;
  font-family: Arial;
}
```

```html
<div class="username-wrapper">
  <div class="username">
    DG
  </div>
</div>
```