# How to make the text clickable?

Tags: html, asp.net

I have added some text to the menu like this: i.e. User's name abbreviation with background color.
There is:  how I make the text:
[How to display image like gmail displays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59345985/how-to-display-image-like-gmail-displays)

I'd like to do the next: click on this text - dialog appears like gmail dialog: 
"Manage account"
"Sign out"
"Register new"

If user clicks outside of the dialog it disappears.

How to make the text clickable with dialog (popup)?

Comment: Do you want to make clickable the static text, or the text that appears in the popup?

Comment: First of all I want to make this text abbreviation clickable and call dialog on click. The dialog will contains the menu as I described above.

Comment: How about wrapping the text in a transparent div and making that clickable?

Comment: Secondly, this is a very broad question, and if you don't know how to do it, you need to go and do some serious learning about Javascript.

Comment: @DavidG, my mistake, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe add a cursor of pointer to the text and then use javascript to add an event listener for when the element is clicked and bring up your dialog.